# Java 8 options for AIX

Tags: java, aix

Does anyone have any information about JDK8 options for AIX environment? As per my information IBM has yet to release Java 8. Are there any other releases of JDK8 for AIX?

Answer (score 3):

For AIX environments, IBM provides his own JVM that is called [J9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_J9).

It currently supports Java from 1.4.2 to 1.8 (Java 8).
SDK can be downloaded at [developerWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/aix/service.html).

I don't know any other **certified** JVM that works under AIX.

There is a project to port [OpenJDK to PowerPC/AIX](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/ppc-aix-port/). It seems to be a bit experimental. See [OpenJDK Wiki](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=13041681) for latest new.

---

*IBM Java SDK 8 was not yet available in the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25995087/2) that mentioned a beta program that is now obsolete since [IBM released Java SDK 8](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21696670) publicly.*

Comment: Oh the joys of naming. I'm looking forward to the Java 9 version of J9.

Comment: Presumably the Java 10 version of J9 will be a peach.